# Расположение разных фигур в прямоугольной области

Tags: алгоритм

Необходимо максимально плотно (без пересечения) разместить различные фигуры, разного размера на изображении.

Вот что получилось сделать с помощью случайных чисел

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кроме очевидной проблемы, подбор координат занимает продолжительное время.

Подскажите, какой алгоритм использовать для решения данной задачи.
Возможно подойдет какая-то библиотека, вроде OpenCV.

Спасибо!

Comment: Это вопрос не по программированию, а по теории алгоритмов. Спросите лучше у вашего научного руководителя.

Comment: Это не научная работа. Нет необходимости в нахождении самого оптимального алгоритма. Нужно чтобы визуально область казалась заполнена равномерно. Должно получится вот так [https://prnt.sc/hq2b7r](https://prnt.sc/hq2b7r) только с разными фигурами.

Comment: Хм. Там, я думаю, алгоритм сначала бросал большие фигуры, а потом меньшие (а потом ещё меньшие и т. д.). Вопрос в определении перекрытия — ну это можно и попиксельно.